# How to fix "Currently, only Gmail extensions may be published." when using G Suite Marketplace SDK?

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

I got an email from Google on "Migration of listing from Chrome Web Store to G Suite Marketplace", so I need to migrate my google doc addon to the Marketplace.  I follow [this](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/publishing-editor-addons) and finally get to "**publish**".  After filled in all fields, I got "**Currently, only Gmail extensions may be published.**" on this step to stop me from publishing.

Do you have any pointers or instructions on how to publish a Google Docs add-on?  I just want to publish this addon for my company that I did before.

[image: G Suite Marketplace SDK]

Answer (score 0):

For the migration you just have to fill in the Configuration tab.

Comment: I did the Configuration tab and can save it.  The error seems telling me that I cannot publish Google Doc extension, but Gmail.

Comment: For Docs add-on you should not use the Publish page, only the Configurations one. You don't need to publish it again. If you give me the project number I can tell you if it's already migrated.

Comment: I got the same problem when clicking "Publish" button in Gsuite Marketplace SDK. I have created the addon in Chrome Webstore listing and the status is published now but there is another status which is "GAM:pending". In Gsụite Marketplace SDK, I have completed all required field and added the link of Chrome Webstore addon to "Universal navigation extension" in Configuration tab and I still got the problem when clicking "Publish" button. What should I do now to solve this problem?

Comment: It's possible that the app is being reviewed. Please create an issue in issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:5106199 including cloud project number (i.e. GSM app ID) and the CWS id.